# Calculating extensions in elastic string

Tags: classical-mechanics

Could anyone please help me with the following question?

[image]

Here's my failed line of reasoning so far:

My diagram:

[image]

You can see that I am assuming that P moves down to lie vertically under it's original position, is even this correct?

Otherwise:

I've tried a few ways, here's the most naive, thanks for any help:

Let extension in AP = $x_1$ and extension in PB be $x_2$ then:

$L_1=\frac{3}{20\,cos\,\theta}$

and so

$x_1=\frac{3}{20\,cos\,\theta}-\frac{3}{20}$

and

$L_2=\frac{1}{20\,sin\,\theta}$

and so

$x_2=\frac{1}{20\,sin\,\theta}-\frac{1}{20}$

Hence:

$\frac{x_1}{x_2}=\frac{\frac{60-60\,cos\,\theta}{400\,cos\,\theta}}{\frac{20-20\,sin\,\theta}{400\,sin\,\theta}}=\frac{60-60\,cos\,\theta}{\cos\theta}\times\frac{sin\,\theta}{20-20\,sin\,\theta}$

which can be simplified to:

$\frac{(3-3\,cos\,\theta)\,sin\,\theta}{(1-sin\,\theta)\,cos\,\theta}$

Which isn't the required answer. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It could be that your assumption that the new point is exactly below the old point, is not right. The force equilibrium in the horizontal tells that the forces have to be equal on both sides, which leads to that the (absolute) elongation has to be equal on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
|AP|_0 = 15\\
|BP|_0 = 5\\
r = \frac{|AP|_0+|BP|_0}{2}\\
|AP| = 2r\cos\theta\\
|BP| = 2r\sin\theta
$$

then

$$
\frac{|AP|-|AP|_0}{|BP|-|BP|_0} = \frac{20 \cos (\theta )-15}{20 \sin (\theta )-5} = \frac{4 \cos (\theta )-3}{4 \sin (\theta )-1}
$$

the solution follows as in 
[Calculation of the modulus of elasticity of a stretched string](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845427/calculation-of-the-modulus-of-elasticity-of-a-stretched-string/2845522#2845522)

NOTE

with $\lambda$ the elastic modulus,

$$
\lambda\left(\frac{|AP|-|AP|_0}{|AP|_0}\right)\cos\theta = \lambda\left(\frac{|BP|-|BP|_0}{|BP|_0}\right)\sin\theta
$$

(In equilibrium the horizontal projection for $F_{AP}$ and $F_{PB}$ are equal) then

$$
\frac{|AP|-|AP|_0}{|BP|-|BP|_0}=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\frac{|AP|_0}{|BP|_0}
$$

or as expected

$$
\frac{4 \cos \theta-3}{4 \sin\theta-1} = 3\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks very much for your work. I'll try an learn from it! Mitch.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my other attempt which does not assume that P moves down vertically:

I'll be using Hooke's law $T=\frac{\lambda x}{a}$

Let h = the height of the triangle in the diagram, i.e. the distance through which P falls.

$h=L_2\,cos\,\theta=L_1\,sin\,\theta$

and so

$L_1=\frac{L_2\,cos\,\theta}{sin\,\theta}$ - call this "Equation A"

$L_2=\frac{L_1\,sin\,\theta}{cos\,\theta}$ - call this "Equation B"

Resolving forces horizontally:

$T_1\,cos\,\theta-T_2\,sin\,\theta=0$ - Call this "Equation 1"

and Hooke's law gives us:

$T_1=\frac{\lambda(L_1-\frac{3}{20})}{\frac{3}{20}}$

and

$T_2=\frac{\lambda(L_2-\frac{1}{20})}{\frac{1}{20}}$

And so Eqaution 1 gives us:

$\frac{20}{3}\lambda(L_1-\frac{3}{20})\,cos\,\theta-20\lambda(L_2-\frac{1}{20})\,sin\,\theta=0$

Substituting fot $L_1$ from Equation A gives:

$\lambda(\frac{20}{3}\times\frac{L_2\,cos\,\theta}{sin\,\theta}-1)\,cos\,\theta=\lambda(20L_2-1)\,sin\,\theta$

Which rearranges to:

$L_2=\frac{3\,sin\theta(cos\,\theta-sin\,\theta)}{20\,cos^2\theta-60\,sin^2\theta}$

Similarly substituting for $L_2$ from Equation B leads to:

$L_1=\frac{3\,cos\theta(cos\,\theta-sin\,\theta)}{20\,cos^2\theta-60\,sin^2\theta}$

Now we are asked to find $\frac{L_1 - \frac{3}{20}}{L_2-\frac{1}{20}}$

Which is equal to:

$\frac{60\,cos\,\theta(cos\,\theta-sin\,\theta)-3(20\,cos^2\theta-60\,sin^2\theta)}{20(cos^2\theta-60\,sin^2\theta)}/\frac{60\,sin\theta(cos\,\theta-sin\,\theta)-(20\,cos^2\theta-60\,sin^2\theta)}{20(cos^2\theta-60\,sin^2\theta)}$

Which simplifies to:

$\frac{9\,sin^2\theta-3\,sin\,\theta\,cos\,\theta}{3\,sin\,\theta\,cos\,\theta-cos^2\theta}$

Which is not the required answer.